# LinearLayout take 50% screen in scrollview android

Tags: android

I am trying to set two two linear layout 50% of screen size inside of a scrollview but the layout is not taking 50% screen size. here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlScrollingPlayList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svPlayList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llScrollingContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:weightSum="100">
               <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50">

                   <Button
                       android:id="@+id/btOne"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_weight="50"
                       android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btTwo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove hight android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: add linear layout `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: remove height has no effect on the layout

Comment: remove scrollview and try

Answer (score 0):

here weight doesnot wor, we need to do it dynamically, use the displaymetrics to get the screen size and then set these parameters as height and width to that layout dynamically

Comment: provide me with an example

Answer (score 0):

```
Display dis = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = dis.getWidth() * 50 / 100;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    width,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                            homeFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with ScrollView is if you don't give height/width in dp or px then ScrollView set all height and width to wrap_content. If you want to divide the screen in two parts better to use scroll inside the devided Layout.

For Ex:

```
<LinearLayout  android:weightSum="1"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:layout_height=0.5
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 <ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout/>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_height=0.5
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 <ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout/>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rlScrollingPlayList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/svPlayList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llScrollingContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

             <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1">

                 <Button
                      android:id="@+id/btOne"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btTwo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove android:layout_height="fill_parent" from both the LinearLayouts. and replace

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

on both of them !

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :-

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llScrollingContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2.0" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#0000FF" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#0FF0FF" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btTwo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and add scrollview dynamically like below code :-

```
LinearLayout maincontainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.weatherInfo);
maincontainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

final HorizontalScrollView scrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(getApplicationContext());
maincontainer.addView(scrollView);

final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
```